# Does Azure blob/file share storage NFS protocol support Windows machine mounting?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, nfsclient, azure-file-share

I was trying to connect with Azure blob storage as well as azure file share with different protocols. I am able to connect with SFTP, SMB protocols from my windows machine, but not able to connect via NFS protocol. Is it possible to connect to blob/file_share via NFS protocol from windows machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/files-nfs-protocol):

> NFS Azure file shares are not supported for Windows clients. Before using NFS Azure file shares for production, see the Troubleshoot NFS Azure file shares article for a list of known issues.

NFS Azure file shares are also only available on the premium tier.

Azure Blob Storage also only support Linux mounts, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support):

> Blob storage now supports the Network File System (NFS) 3.0 protocol. This support provides Linux file system compatibility at object storage scale and prices and enables Linux clients to mount a container in Blob storage from an Azure Virtual Machine (VM) or a computer on-premises.